# Is there a function/method to extract child elements from a child element?

Tags: java, xml, dom

Noob here. I'm trying to read a xml file to java using DOM, importing data from different objects. Since the elements are nested, I'm trying to reach every child and grandchild information and I can't read the grandchild info.

this is an example of the file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <AAAA>
        <BBBB>
            <CCC>text</CCC>
            <DDD>
                <a>value</a>
                <b>value</b>
                <c>value</c>
            </DDD>
            <EEE>
                <aa>
                    <a>text</a>
                    <b>
                      <a>value</a>
                      <b>value</b>
                      <c>value</c>
                    </b>
                </aa>
                <bb>
                    <a>text</a>
                    <b>
                      <a>value</a>
                      <b>value</b>
                      <c>value</c>
                    </b>
                </bb>
             </EEE>
        </BBBB>
    </AAAA>
```

I can reach the  node but not the following ones.

This is part of the code I have so far:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static List<BBBB> readXMLFileToList(File file) {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
        List<BBBB> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();


            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("AAAA");

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                list.add(getBBBB(nodeList.item(i)));
            }
        } catch (SAXException | ParserConfigurationException | IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();

        }
        return list;
    }


    private static BBBB getBBBB (Node node) {

        BBBB bbbb = null;
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element element = (Element) node;
            String ccc = getTagValue("CCC", element);
            if (dddNode.getNodeName().trim().equals("#text")) {
                dddNode = element.getFirstChild().getNextSibling();
            }
            DDD ddd = getDDD(dddNode);
            bbbb = new BBBB (ccc, ddd);

        }

        return bbbb;
    }


    private static DDD getDDD(Node node) {
        Element element = (Element) node;
        Double a = Double.parseDouble(getTagValue("a", element));
        Double b = Double.parseDouble(getTagValue("b", element));
        Double c = Double.parseDouble(getTagValue("c", element));
        DDD ddd = new DDD (a,b,c);
        return ddd;
    }
```

Comment: your code samples please

Comment: hello, just updated my post!